# How do i change background colour of parent div?

Tags: html, css

How do I get the background of my website, outside of divs, to be a color?
Here a sample of my code:

```
.div1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:400px;
    width:1000px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: none ;
    image-repeat: no-repeat;
    img-position: top right;
    text-align: left
}


.div2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:750px;
    width:1000px;
    margin-left: none ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    text-align: center
}


.div3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:470px;
    width:1000px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: none ;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried everything I could think of and I achieved nothing.

Comment: Set a background-color on the parent container or body?

Comment: having hard time trying to understand what do you want.....

Comment: @kmdm is correct.  You can set the body to have a certain background-color, i.e. `body {background-color: #ccc;}`.  Alternatively, you could wrap the whole page in a div that is a specific background-color, i.e. `div.page-wrapper {width: 100%; background-color: #ccc;} `

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. I want to have my body back ground color set. Basically have the web page have 3 divs and the rest of it to be a color like red.

Comment: http://html.net/tutorials/css/lesson3.php

Comment: @Jon , you could edit your question, and add this sentence ("I want to have my body back ground color set. Basically have the web page have 3 divs and the rest of it to be a color like red."), then it won't be downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the background color of the parent `div`, which is the `div` surrounding `div1`, `div2` & `div3`.

Here is an example [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/fgm5yjoz/9/)

Comment: You can also learn alot by looking at tutorials.  I recomend https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp :)

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple code example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Test Table</title>

        <style type="text/css"> 
            body {
                background-color: orange;
            }

            .div1 {
                border: 1px solid black;
                height:400px;
                width:1000px;
                margin-left: auto ;
                margin-right: none ;
                text-align: left;
                background-color: blue;
            }

            .div2 {
                border: 1px solid black;
                height:750px;
                width:1000px;
                margin-left: none ;
                margin-right: auto ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: left;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: green;
            }

            .div3 {
                border: 1px solid black;
                height:470px;
                width:1000px;
                margin-left: auto ;
                margin-right: none ;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="div1">DIV 1</div>
        <div class="div2">DIV 2</div>  
        <div class="div3">DIV 3</div>  
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.div1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: none ;
    image-repeat: no-repeat;
    img-position: top right;
    text-align: left
}


.div2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    margin-left: none ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    text-align: center
}


.div3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: none ;
}
```

```html
<div class='div1'>div 1</div>
<div class='div2'>div 2</div>
<div class='div3'>div 3</div>
```